# Custom Bert and unresolved self.init_weights()

Tags: python, bert-language-model

currently I get a warning about unresolved attribute reference self.iniit_weights() in my customized Bert. Do you know how I can fix it? Neural networks and transformers are very new to me. I use thew newest version of transformers 4.9.1 and python 3.8.

My Bert class looks like this and is very similar to an example found online, it only has more classifiers.

```
class MyBert(BertPreTrainedModel):

    def __init__(self, config, num_labels1=None, num_labels2=None, num_labels3=None):
        super().__init__(config)
        self.num_labels1 = num_labels1
        self.num_labels2 = num_labels2
        self.num_labels3 = num_labels3
        self.bert = BertModel(config)
        self.dropout = torch.nn.Dropout(config.hidden_dropout_prob)
        self.classifier1 = torch.nn.Linear(config.hidden_size, num_labels1)
        self.classifier2 = torch.nn.Linear(config.hidden_size, num_labels2)
        self.classifier3 = torch.nn.Linear(config.hidden_size, num_labels3)
        self.init_weights() # unresolved attribute reference
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you still need help for so long, but here are things about your model:
Since you were using `transformers` I believe the your model is a subclass of `BertPreTrainedModel` which is a subclass of `PreTrainedModel`, and this is where the method `init_weights()` comes from. 
The link to the documentation is [here](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.17.0/en/main_classes/model#transformers.PreTrainedModel.init_weights)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31327469)